# Exporting points inside specific polygon to Excel spreadsheet using QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, export, excel, point-in-polygon

I have two vector layers, one with points, and the other with catchment boundaries. This is showing where the points are in relation to catchment areas.

I want to be able to export a Excel file that will allow me to see the points broken down into each catchment.

Lets say the points are hospitals, and I want to be able to find out how many hospitals each catchment area has. One layer is the catchment area and the other vector is the hospitals. but both sets of data don't have any matching attributes so I cant export the layers data then match them up using matching `"id"`'s

I have attached an image to help explain. The catchment is the green and the points in maroon.

[image]

Comment: So, what is you question? What have you tried to answer it?

Comment: I want to have an excel spreadsheet that I can sort by catchment area, and then I can see the points under each catchment area. Lets say the points are hospitals, and I want to be able to find out how many hospitals each catchment area area has. one vector is the catchment area and the other vector is the hospitals. but both sets of data don't have any matching attributes so i can jut match them up that way.

Comment: So, you want to know how to `join attributes by location`?

Comment: That could be a start.

Comment: I suggest you try the tool yourself. Its fairly easy to handle.

Comment: Or this one [Selecting and exporting points inside specific polygon using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/412639/selecting-and-exporting-points-inside-specific-polygon-using-qgis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On the point layer, create a new field with Field calculator to get the catchment area each point is within. Use this expression (replace `polygon` with the name of the catchment layer, `id` with the name of the field from there that you want: `array_first(overlay_within ('polygon', id))`.
2. `Right click layer / Export /Save Features as...` and select `Comma Separated Values (CSV)` as output format. Then Open this in Excel.